# close colorbox doesn't work with chrome

Tags: google-chrome, colorbox

I have a very big problem, I’m developping a site web and I’m using `colorbox plugin`. It’s very nice, but I have a big problem with `Google Chrome browser` because :

`parent.$.fn.colorbox.close()` doesn’t work in Google Chrome

Please help me to find a solution to this issue !

Answer (score 0):

I've used ColorBox extensively with Chrome on the following OS: Windows, Linux (Ubuntu), so I doubt the browser is the issue.

Are you developing locally or using a server web server? This is important because Chrome can be more strict about cross-site scripting enforcement.

Perhaps you can say more about what 'doesn't work' (like what are you seeing in the Chrome console applet?) or better yet, post a link to your project.

Regards, KJM

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with chrome v.21

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/EuOiRG4Bdf8

A lot of colorbox features are bugged since the las chrome update.